# CGCC Blog Post #6: My First Impression on Code Golf Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, new-users, cgcc-blog

### How I got here

I saw a few sites of Stack Exchange elsewhere. Exactly where I forgot, but it made the first impression of Stack Overflow to me: they were indeed very sophisticated. I learned about Code Golf Stack Exchange (which I will shorten to CGSE) when something led me to this link: [Produce the number 2014 without any numbers in your source code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code/17103#17103). The answer was **AMAZING**!!!

### Why I signed in

I first signed in to post an answer to a question. It was quite a good and fun polyglot. After that, I found Code Golf quite interesting and tried to post questions and answers.

### So back to my first impression

#### Organized

I personally think CGSE is quite organized.

You add tags to your question. This helps clarify what your question is mainly about, and makes a lot of tasks easier. For instance, it means that people are more capable of answering your question.

#### Friendly

CGSE is very friendly to new users. Other users treat me respectively.

There is a "Code of Conduct". People pay attention to treating everyone equally and respectfully. There is a "New Contributor Tag" for new users, and people take more time in telling them.

There are friendly reminders of doing practically **anything**. From formatting and how to ask a good question to questions that are relatively similar. It is very beginner-friendly.

There is no doubt that other users helped a lot, namely, caird coinheringaahing, Jo King, Unrelated String, etc. They helped a lot. Without them I am probably not going to make such good questions.

#### Challenging

All the problems are challenging. It takes about a week to make a question and make it understandable. Then it takes another week to get an answer, so people tend to polish their questions in the sandbox.

#### CGSE get rids of loopholes

Loopholes are really funny, but they are relatively useless, and thus CGSE get rids of them, making sure there are only useful answers. It makes sure everything is useful to users. This makes questions more focused.

Comment: We can't control the 40m limit, it's network-wide. But a good challenge should take about that long to write anyway :p

Comment: Once you get a certain amount of reputation, I think it's 1000, the limit goes away.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I'm not sure how they determine it. The limit went away for me network-wide when my reputation on Law.SE (the site where i have the highest reputation) was about 600-700, IIRC.

Comment: My first impression is unfortunately: cargo cult. The so-called "standard rules" and the heavy acceptance for non-standard extensions etc means that the so-called languages used in the examples here are very different from the actual languages. So the solutions posted aren't even programming language flavours for a specific compiler version, they are for a local "CGSE" flavour of the language. And this makes the site uninteresting to participate on, since everything has to be adapted to the artificial shortcuts dictated on this site. It's basically golf where you move tee to the edge of green.